# ASP Server tag not rendering

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap to collapse and expand a details view for policies. I have the below code and my server tag is not resolving to the client id and stays as <%= details.ClientID %> in the html code. I have the exact same code on a different page and it is working fine. Am I missing something? The details ID is resolving to the asp server ID properly, just my data-target isn't changing.

```
<asp:Repeater ...>
    <tr class="text-right" data-target="#<%= details.ClientID %>" data-toggle="collapse">
        <td>Policies</td>
    </tr>
    <tr runat="server" ID="details" class="collapse">
        <asp:Repeater ....>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tr>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: You have a typo there `%<=`

Comment: Your `%<` characters are transposed.

Comment: I switched them but it still isn't resolving.

Comment: Wouldn't you use something like `DataBinder.Eval()` inside a `Repeater`?  What is `details` and where does that come from?  Is the `Repeater` working *at all*?  Can you create a more complete example and show the specific resulting HTML?

Comment: The code is working perfectly. Unfortunately, I'm working as a contractor and am under an NDA so I can't just copy and paste my code so I have to clean it up a bit. The "Policies" row is essentially a category header and the details is an expandable group that contains a list of all their policies of that type. If in the chrome dev tools I copy and replace the `#<%= details.ClientID %>` with the rendered ID, the collapse/expand logic works. I basically just need to figure out why the data target is not rendering properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just doing it through Javascript:

```
$('#<%=detailsParent.ClientID%>').attr('data-target', '#<%=details.ClientID%>');
```